# Inverse Trigonometry Problem

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

So there is the question $\cos(\arcsin(4/5))$. Normally if it is a $30-60-90$ or $45-45-90$, it is easy to compute. But with a $3-4-5$ special triangle, I am wondering how you calculate it without using a calculator.

Second, does anyone know if $(\arcsin^{-1}(x))$ equal $1/\arcsin(x)$ or just $\sin(x)$, although I believe it should be the latter one.

Comment: Draw a triangle in the standard position (first quadrant, start from the x-axis, etc). The sine (opp/hyp) is 4/5, so label the opposite $4$ and the hypotenuse $5$. The adjacent side is $3$, by the Pythagorean theorem. Then take the cosine of the angle.

Comment: Hint: what is $\sin(\arcsin(\frac{4}{5}))$?

Answer (score 2):

Starting with the second question: $\arcsin^{-1}(x)=\sin(x)$ and conversely $\sin^{-1}(x)=\arcsin(x)$

Then for the first use $\cos(y)=\sqrt{1-(\sin(y))^2}$ and substitue what you learned from the second question. What do you get?

> $\cos(\arcsin(4/5))=\sqrt{1-(\sin(\arcsin(4/5)))^2}=...?$

Comment: I think I get it. Thanks

Comment: @CoolKid you're welcome...

Answer (score 2):

We have
$$
\sin \alpha = 4 / 5 \Rightarrow \alpha = \arcsin(4/5)
$$
You do not have to calculate the value for $\alpha$. 
However looking at the desired expression we get
$$ 
\cos(\arcsin(4/5)) = \cos(\alpha)
$$
and this you can infer from a sketch:

[image: sketch]
([Large version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxwtM.png))

The expression
$$
\arcsin^{-1}(x)
$$
means the inverse function of $\arcsin(x)$, thus a function $f$ which satisfies
$$
f(\arcsin(x)) = \arcsin(f(x)) = x
$$

Answer (score 1):

You can easily calculate it by hand, using $\;\sin(\arcsin x)=x$ for all $x\in[-1,1]$, and Pythagoras's identity:
$$\cos^2(\arcsin 4/5)=1-\sin^2(\arcsin 4/5)=\frac9{25},$$
whence $\;\cos(\arcsin 4/5)=\pm\dfrac35$. To decide which is the correct value, notethat, by definition, the range of $\arcsin$, is $\bigl[-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2\bigr]$, so the correct value is $\;+\dfrac35$.

Concerning your second question, $\;\dfrac1{\arcsin x}$ would usually also denoted $(\arcsin x)^{-1}$, and $\arcsin^{-1}$ is not exactly $\sin$, but the *restriction* of $\sin$ to the interval $\bigl[-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2\bigr]$.

Answer (score 0):

The angles of a $3$-$4$-$5$ triangle are $37^\circ,53^\circ$ and $90^\circ$.  $$\sin^{-1}(4/5)=53^\circ.$$ Hope this helps you to solve the problem.

Comment: Yeah... not sure where you're going with this. Are we to then take the cosine of 53 degrees? Because that's $0.601815023...$

Comment: No cosine of 53 is $(3/5)$. Which is only $0.6$.

Comment: Where are you getting this information? The number I transcribed above was from google.